# Connecting existing addEndpoint() to existing makeTarget() in jsPlumb

Tags: jsplumb

I have seen elsewhere the following technique for attaching existing endpoints. This works fine when both the source and target are created using `addEndpoint()`

```
var e0 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("container0",{uuid:"ep1"}),  //set your own uuid for endpoint for later access.
var e1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("container1",{uuid:"ep2"});  
jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:[e1.getUuid(),e2.getUudi()] }); // (or) jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:["ep1","ep2"] });
```

However, in my case I need to join and endpoint to a target created using `makeTarget()`

```
var e0 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("container0",{uuid:"ep1"}),  //set your own uuid for endpoint for later access.
var e1 = jsPlumb.makeTarget("container1",{uuid:"ep2"});  
jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:[e1.getUuid(),e2.getUudi()] }); // (or) jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:["ep1","ep2"] });
```

However this does not work and the returned results from `makeTarget()` does not even have a `getUuid()` method.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
jsPlumb.connect({
    source: sourceUUID,
    target: targetID,
    uuids: [sourceUUID, targetID],
    editable: true
});
```